# $x_n=n^{3/2}(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}-2\sqrt{n})$. Find out if it has limit or not (with proof)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I was able to prove that $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}-2\sqrt{n} $ has limit that equals zero. But obviously $n^{3/2}$ does not have limit in rational numbers. How to find result limit?

Note: if it has limit then find $N(\epsilon)$ where $N(\epsilon)$ is function that connects $N$ and $\epsilon$ from epsilon definition of limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}){(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} }=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} }.$$
Similarly
$$\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n}=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1} },$$
so
$$\begin{gather}\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}-2\sqrt{n} = (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) + (\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n}) = \\
= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n} } - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1} } = \dfrac{\sqrt{n-1} - \sqrt{n+1}}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n})} = \\
= \dfrac{-2}{(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n})}.
\end{gather}$$
Now we can calculate the desired limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{x_n} = -2 \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[{\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n+1})} \cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n})}}\right] =\\ = -2\cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} =  -\dfrac{1}{4}$$